# A series of factors or an equation?

Tags: equation-solving

Is there anybody that can help me simplify the following ideas in an equation, a series of factors or whatever mathematical form is easier to later use and understand?
They all have to be true.

x = (z/2)

x = ((z+y)/3)

z - y = a

y - x = a

X ≠ 0

The main idea is that the diference between x and y is the same as the one between y and z. And that 3x is always the same as z + y and 2x is the same as z. Does this have a solution? If not I have to at least make it work with

3x > z+y

and

2x > z

instead of the first two arguments...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to Mathematica

Answer (score 1):

`Reduce` evaluates only

```
Reduce[x == z/2 && x == (z + y)/3 && z - y == a && a == y - x]
(*z == 0 && y == 0 && x == 0 && a == 0*)
```

the trivial solution!

With modified "inequality conditions"

```
 Reduce[x > z/2 && x > (z + y)/3 && z - y == a && a == y - x]
 (*((z <= 0 && y > (3 z)/4) || (z > 0 && y > (4 z)/5)) && x == 2 y - z &&a == -y + z*)
```

Comment: Thanks Ulrich. I forgot to say that X ≠ 0 ☺️

Comment: In this case there is no solution! Add   this condition to `Reduce[…&&x!=0]`

Comment: If not is it possible we make it work with

3x > z+y

and

2x > z

instead of the first two arguments?

Comment: You could try yourself `Reduce[x > z/2 && x > (z + y)/3 && z - y == a && a == y - x]`

Comment: Thank you. Pardon my total lack of experience with this but what do you use to do this reduction? Do you know an online "calculator" that could help me? I've tried this: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/equation-calculator/Reduce%5Cleft%5Bx%20%3E%20z%2F2%20%20x%20%3E%20%5Cleft(z%20%2B%20y%5Cright)%2F3%20%20z%20-%20y%20%3D%3D%20a%20%20a%20%3D%3D%20y%20-%20x%5Cright%5D

Comment: Sorry I assumed you would be a Mathematica user. I modified my answer. Perhaps wolframalpha is an online calculator you could use.